# HTTP test code in C using POST request returns 405 status code

Tags: c, http, post, client, recv

I have written a test code that first connects to a web server. It then requests a page, which has a login form, using GET. The GET works and a 200 status code is returned from the web server. After retrieving the page, I attempt to send a POST request to send some log in information but instead receive a 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED status code in return.

Here is the code for sending the GET:

```
char data[273] = "GET /login HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.minecraft.net\r\nUser-Agent: Web-sniffer/1.0.37 (+http://web-sniffer.net/)\r\nAccept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nAccept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3\r\nReferer: http://web-sniffer.net/\r\n\r\n";
if ((val = send(sockfd, &data,272,0)) == -1){
    perror("send");
}
```

And here is the code containing the POST command, username and password are changed so no personal information is given out:

```
char data2[405] = "POST /login HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.minecraft.net\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Web-sniffer/1.0.37 (+http://web-sniffer.net/)\r\nAccept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nAccept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3\r\nReferer: http://web-sniffer.net/\r\nContent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-length: 38\r\n\r\nusername=ausername&password=apassword";
if ((val = send(sockfd, &data2,404,0)) == -1){
    perror("send");
}
```

To make the packets readable:

```
GET /login HTTP/1.1[CRLF]
Host: www.minecraft.net[CRLF]
User-Agent: Web-sniffer/1.0.37 (+http://web-sniffer.net/)[CRLF]
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7[CRLF]
Cache-Control: no-cache[CRLF]
Accept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3[CRLF]
Referer: http://web-sniffer.net/[CRLF]
[CRLF]
```

And the POST packet:

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1[CRLF]
Host: www.minecraft.net[CRLF]
Connection: close[CRLF]
User-Agent: Web-sniffer/1.0.37 (+http://web-sniffer.net/)[CRLF]
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7[CRLF]
Cache-Control: no-cache[CRLF]
Accept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3[CRLF]
Referer: http://web-sniffer.net/[CRLF]
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded[CRLF]
Content-length: 38[CRLF]
[CRLF]
username=ausername&password=apassword
```

As you may notice, the User-Agent is Web-sniffer as I used web-sniffer.net to make these packets, which worked on their website as the POST command there returned a 302 FOUND status code.

I am wondering why this behavior is observed here when the exact same packets worked on web-sniffer.net, yet don't work here.

Comment: Are they identical server implementations? One wouldn't necessarily expect a login mechanism that works on one server to work on another. Looking at the source for www.minecraft.net, the login destination is https://www.minecraft.net/login (not http), which could be the specific cause here.

Comment: The address not having http indicates that it doesn't use http as the login mechanism?

Comment: For web sniffer packet generation, it will create the POST packet if you go to http://web-sniffer.net/ and in the URL box type in www.minecraft.net/login?username=avalidusername&password=avalidpassword

Comment: You'd need to check the "Connect to ..." line above the packet details. The packets for http and https could otherwise look the same, but they're essentially going to different sites.

Comment: you mean the Host: line?

Comment: Nope, web-sniffer gives you a line before the HTTP like this "Connect to 107.22.210.22 on port 443 ... ok". Your C code doesn't show which server you've connected `sockfd` to.

Comment: ah, I did a little researching, so I need to both deal with two sockfd's, one for port 80 and http and a sockfd for port 443 dealing with https

Comment: Originally, the client was only using port 80